# Approximating inverse of a matrix using truncated Taylor series

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I want to compute Taylor series of a real square matrix, say $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ using Taylor expansion of the function $y=\frac{1}{x}$

First of all, it is somehow ambiguous to me about how Taylor series of a real valued function relates to computing inverse of a matrix, I've heard about Neumann series but I am looking for a simpler explanation, I want some intuition based on Taylor series for function $\frac{1}{x}$

So I know that the Taylor series of $\frac{1}{x}$ around an arbitrary point $x=c$ is given by: $\sum_{n>=0} \frac{(-c)^{-n}\times(-c + x)^n}{c}$

But here are my questions:

1. What is the relationship of above series for a function with approximation of inverse of a matrix, specifically, what is $c$ here for a matrix? for a real function we know that $c$ is a point we wrote above series around that but what about a matrix?
2. I know to convergence interval for Taylor series of a real-valued function, but what is the convergence interval for a approximation a matrix inverse?

To sum up, I have never heard of Taylor expansion of a matrix let alone its inverse!

Answer (score 1):

You can always calculate $p(M)$ when $p$ is a polynomial and $M$ is a square matrix. So if you have a Taylor expansion of $f(x)$ you can hope that plugging $M$ into a  polynomial approximation of $f$ will give you an approximation to what you want to call $f(M)$.

In particular, you can always define $e^M$ this way.

For inverses, sometimes the geometric series
$$
\frac{1}{1-x} = 1 + x + x^2 + x^3 + \cdots
$$
gives good approximations to $(1-M)^{-1}$.

Comment: Thanks, you said 'sometimes' geometric series gives good approximation, what is exactly that 'sometimes'?

Comment: Well, since $(I-M)(I+M+M^2+\ldots+M^{n-1}) = I-M^n$ holds, the "error" in approximating it with $n$ terms is $M^N$, and you can take the [norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm) of your choice to turn that into a real value. This will be related to the [spectral radius](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_radius) of $M$, which basically means that if the largest eigenvalue of $M$ (in absolute terms) is less than 1, the error will decrease as the number of terms in the series increases.